# I am getting this error in my flask web app: AttributeError: 'GradientBoostingClassifier' object has no attribute '_loss'

Tags: python

My code was working perfectly until yesterday but when I ran it today, it gave me the following error: **AttributeError: 'GradientBoostingClassifier' object has no attribute '_loss'**
I am attaching my code as well. Please let me know the issue soon.

I have installed all the necessary libraries like pandas numpy scikit-learn flask. What could be the reason that it suddenly gave this error. When I try to run this program it gives the 500 internal server error. Please help!

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os
import pickle 

model = pickle.load(open('model.sav','rb'))



TEMPLATE_DIR= os.path.abspath('templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.abspath('static')

app = Flask("__name__", template_folder=TEMPLATE_DIR, static_folder=STATIC_DIR)

df_1=pd.read_csv("first_telc.csv")

q = ""

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html', query="")

@app.route("/homepage")
def home():
    return render_template('indexpage.html', query="")

@app.route("/analysis", methods=['GET','POST'])
def analysis():
    return render_template('churnfile.html', query="")

@app.route("/prediction", methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():

    
        '''
    SeniorCitizen
    MonthlyCharges
    TotalCharges
    gender
    Partner
    Dependents
    PhoneService
    MultipleLines
    InternetService
    OnlineSecurity
    OnlineBackup
    DeviceProtection
    TechSupport
    StreamingTV
    StreamingMovies
    Contract
    PaperlessBilling
    PaymentMethod
    tenure
    '''
        if request.method == 'POST':
            inputQuery1  = request.form['query1']
            inputQuery2  = request.form['query2']
            inputQuery3  = request.form['query3']
            inputQuery4  = request.form['query4']
            inputQuery5  = request.form['query5']
            inputQuery6  = request.form['query6']
            inputQuery7  = request.form['query7']
            inputQuery8  = request.form['query8']
            inputQuery9  = request.form['query9']
            inputQuery10 = request.form['query10']
            inputQuery11 = request.form['query11']
            inputQuery12 = request.form['query12']
            inputQuery13 = request.form['query13']
            inputQuery14 = request.form['query14']
            inputQuery15 = request.form['query15']
            inputQuery16 = request.form['query16']
            inputQuery17 = request.form['query17']
            inputQuery18 = request.form['query18']
            inputQuery19 = request.form['query19']

            

            

            data = [[inputQuery1, inputQuery2, inputQuery3, inputQuery4, inputQuery5, inputQuery6, inputQuery7, 
             inputQuery8, inputQuery9, inputQuery10, inputQuery11, inputQuery12, inputQuery13, inputQuery14,
             inputQuery15, inputQuery16, inputQuery17, inputQuery18, inputQuery19]]

            new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['SeniorCitizen', 'MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges', 'gender', 
                                           'Partner', 'Dependents', 'PhoneService', 'MultipleLines', 'InternetService',
                                           'OnlineSecurity', 'OnlineBackup', 'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport',
                                           'StreamingTV', 'StreamingMovies', 'Contract', 'PaperlessBilling',
                                           'PaymentMethod', 'tenure'])


            df_2 = pd.concat([df_1, new_df], ignore_index = True) 
            # Group the tenure in bins of 12 months
            labels = ["{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 11) for i in range(1, 72, 12)]

            df_2['tenure_group'] = pd.cut(df_2.tenure.astype(int), range(1, 80, 12), right=False, labels=labels)
            #drop column customerID and tenure
            df_2.drop(columns= ['tenure'], axis=1, inplace=True)   

            new_df__dummies = pd.get_dummies(df_2[['gender', 'SeniorCitizen', 'Partner', 'Dependents', 'PhoneService',
           'MultipleLines', 'InternetService', 'OnlineSecurity', 'OnlineBackup',
           'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport', 'StreamingTV', 'StreamingMovies',
           'Contract', 'PaperlessBilling', 'PaymentMethod','tenure_group']])

            single = model.predict(new_df__dummies.tail(1))
            probablity = model.predict_proba(new_df__dummies.tail(1))[:,1]
    
            if single==1:
             o1 = "This customer is likely to be churned!!"
             o2 = "Confidence: {}".format(probablity*100)
            else:
             o1 = "This customer is likely to continue!!"
             o2 = "Confidence: {}".format(probablity*100)
        
            return render_template('prediction.html', output1=o1, output2=o2, 
                           query1  = request.form['query1'], 
                           query2  = request.form['query2'],
                           query3  = request.form['query3'],
                           query4  = request.form['query4'],
                           query5  = request.form['query5'], 
                           query6  = request.form['query6'], 
                           query7  = request.form['query7'], 
                           query8  = request.form['query8'], 
                           query9  = request.form['query9'], 
                           query10 = request.form['query10'], 
                           query11 = request.form['query11'], 
                           query12 = request.form['query12'], 
                           query13 = request.form['query13'], 
                           query14 = request.form['query14'], 
                           query15 = request.form['query15'], 
                           query16 = request.form['query16'], 
                           query17 = request.form['query17'],
                           query18 = request.form['query18'], 
                           query19 = request.form['query19'])
        else:
            return render_template('prediction.html', query="")


app.run()
```

This is the complete error:

```
C:\Users\Iram\Desktop\Customer_Churn\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:493: FutureWarning: The feature names should match those that were passed during fit. Starting version 1.2, an error will be raised.
Feature names unseen at fit time:
- SeniorCitizen_0
- SeniorCitizen_1
Feature names seen at fit time, yet now missing:
- MonthlyCharges
- SeniorCitizen
- TotalCharges

  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
[2022-05-26 23:51:33,731] ERROR in app: Exception on /prediction [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Iram\Desktop\Customer_Churn\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Iram\Desktop\Customer_Churn\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Iram\Desktop\Customer_Churn\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Iram\Desktop\Customer_Churn\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 108, in predict
    single = model.predict(new_df__dummies.tail(1))
  File "C:\Users\Iram\Desktop\Customer_Churn\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_gb.py", line 1449, in predict
    raw_predictions = self.decision_function(X)
  File "C:\Users\Iram\Desktop\Customer_Churn\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_gb.py", line 1405, in decision_function
    raw_predictions = self._raw_predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\Iram\Desktop\Customer_Churn\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_gb.py", line 817, in _raw_predict
    raw_predictions = self._raw_predict_init(X)
  File "C:\Users\Iram\Desktop\Customer_Churn\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_gb.py", line 810, in _raw_predict_init
    raw_predictions = self._loss.get_init_raw_predictions(X, self.init_).astype(
AttributeError: 'GradientBoostingClassifier' object has no attribute '_loss'

        
    
    
     
    
        
    x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LET ME FIX THAT FOR YOU**

*First of all if it was working yesterday , it should work today.*

- Diagnosis:  This problem faces Gradient Boosting Classifier (GBC) mainly, it
  does not affect many other algos such as the ANN or DT to name a
  few.
- Cause:      When pickling the fitted model some attributes gets left out, _loss
  attribute  is typical. That is a GBC design issue inherent int its
  computational model that multiprocessing demands.
- Solution: i) Simple solution would be to Add the code for model fitting and
  pickle dumping (saving) code within this same source file. Then
  that pickle loading instruction in your code should follow. That
  will fix it.  See code illustration below.

  ```
        ii) Alternative, a bit complex solution would be to write some 
            multiprocessing code to fit the model within its own separate 
            multiprocessing pools.
  ```

> Blockquote

"Alternative (ii) will demand you a extreme high efforts to accomplish. I advice you go for alternative (i). See code illustration below.

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os
import pickle

#INSERT MODEL FIT AND PICKLE DUMP CODE HERE, BEFORE THAT FOLLOWING MODEL LOAD

model = pickle.load(open('model.sav','rb')) #This load instruction, should follow
#after the suggestions i gave you
#THEN IT WILL WORK

#Here after the rest of your code should follow just as in your old source file.

#THE REST OF YOUR CODE NOW SHOULD GO THERE, I WOULD HAVE CREATED A DUMMY DATASET #TO FULL RUN THIS CODE WITHOUT YOUR INITIAL CODE, BUT I HAD SAME ISSUE, I FIXED THIS WAY

Comment: It would make answer a bit clearer, if you'd surround provided code snippet in markdown code section. Just put tripple tickmarks (```) before and after code snippet. Additionally providing language would enable syntax highlighting. ```python
#code goes here
```

Comment: I illustrated what I mean in that code take a look, for gradient boosting you might need to fit it and call it on the same source file, to avoid the _loss attribute not to persist across different processes.  What happens is when the model is being fitted there is a multiprocessing requirement with gradient boosting. for many other algorithms other than gradient boosting you can use your old approach.

Comment: As you would be using this naive approach of fitting and using the fitteds model to do predictions, then it would might be necessary to do some multiprocessing as much code is running on same source, you can read more on multiprocessing here https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing/

Comment: Finally, so for the case of in capital letters GRADIENT BOOSTING CLASSIFIER, with this approach you might even not need to use pickle at all, as pickle is used only for saving and loading,  .If you want to deploy it then flask only will do. To reduce the time complexity all models other than GB you could implement like u did, but for this one you could do it this way,  that code i sent by it self it shud work as is, if you just supply to it the right training dateset and you training parameters of choice based on the  test accuracy.

Comment: you are welcome for any further clarification, that code has the pickle redundant code, after it runs, you can restructure it to remove the redundancy as I explained, and u could do the multiprocessing if you want, but for multiprocessing is just an additional tip if u will want to reduce computational time.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and turned out that it was caused by a mismatch in my scikit-learn versions. The model I trained and saved was from `scikit-learn==0.22` and but then in my `requirements.txt` I had `scikit-learn==1.1.1`.

See the `heroku log -tails`:

```
2022-08-04T10:32:04.050594+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:329: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator GradientBoostingClassifier from version 0.22 when using version 1.1.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results.
```

So I fixed it by retraining and saving the model with `scikit-learn==1.1.1` and it worked!

Comment: Saved me hours of debugging! cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

how are you,

Are you deploying your source code within at least 2 different source files?

if yes , which I believe it could be so as I do not see the instruction where you reload your model for use in predictions, therefore, I would suggest that you maintain the model loading code within the same source as the model save, this is so in order to allow the necessary _loss function from sklearn.ensemble to be visible within these saved vs loaded model for prediction.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os
import pickle 

#Assume the training datafile data is okay and clean is called data.csv, Load data and split data
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv") 
features = data.drop['Target']
target = data['Target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =\
    train_test_split(features, target, test_size=.4, random_state=42)

#Fit the model, you should involve the required hyper parameters, here I left blank to use defaults
model = GradientBoostingClassifier().fit(X_train,y_train)
#Then evaluate that model with test data, once satisfied with accuracy 

#Then Save it with picke.dump
pickle_out = open("./model.sav", "wb")
pickle.dump(model, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()



model = pickle.load(open('model.sav','rb')) 

TEMPLATE_DIR= os.path.abspath('templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.abspath('static')

app = Flask("__name__", template_folder=TEMPLATE_DIR, static_folder=STATIC_DIR)

df_1=pd.read_csv("first_telc.csv")

q = ""

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html', query="")

@app.route("/homepage")
def home():
    return render_template('indexpage.html', query="")

@app.route("/analysis", methods=['GET','POST'])
def analysis():
    return render_template('churnfile.html', query="")

@app.route("/prediction", methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():

    
        '''
    SeniorCitizen
    MonthlyCharges
    TotalCharges
    gender
    Partner
    Dependents
    PhoneService
    MultipleLines
    InternetService
    OnlineSecurity
    OnlineBackup
    DeviceProtection
    TechSupport
    StreamingTV
    StreamingMovies
    Contract
    PaperlessBilling
    PaymentMethod
    tenure
    '''
        if request.method == 'POST':
            inputQuery1  = request.form['query1']
            inputQuery2  = request.form['query2']
            inputQuery3  = request.form['query3']
            inputQuery4  = request.form['query4']
            inputQuery5  = request.form['query5']
            inputQuery6  = request.form['query6']
            inputQuery7  = request.form['query7']
            inputQuery8  = request.form['query8']
            inputQuery9  = request.form['query9']
            inputQuery10 = request.form['query10']
            inputQuery11 = request.form['query11']
            inputQuery12 = request.form['query12']
            inputQuery13 = request.form['query13']
            inputQuery14 = request.form['query14']
            inputQuery15 = request.form['query15']
            inputQuery16 = request.form['query16']
            inputQuery17 = request.form['query17']
            inputQuery18 = request.form['query18']
            inputQuery19 = request.form['query19']

            

            

            data = [[inputQuery1, inputQuery2, inputQuery3, inputQuery4, inputQuery5, inputQuery6, inputQuery7, 
             inputQuery8, inputQuery9, inputQuery10, inputQuery11, inputQuery12, inputQuery13, inputQuery14,
             inputQuery15, inputQuery16, inputQuery17, inputQuery18, inputQuery19]]

            new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['SeniorCitizen', 'MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges', 'gender', 
                                           'Partner', 'Dependents', 'PhoneService', 'MultipleLines', 'InternetService',
                                           'OnlineSecurity', 'OnlineBackup', 'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport',
                                           'StreamingTV', 'StreamingMovies', 'Contract', 'PaperlessBilling',
                                           'PaymentMethod', 'tenure'])


            df_2 = pd.concat([df_1, new_df], ignore_index = True) 
            # Group the tenure in bins of 12 months
            labels = ["{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 11) for i in range(1, 72, 12)]

            df_2['tenure_group'] = pd.cut(df_2.tenure.astype(int), range(1, 80, 12), right=False, labels=labels)
            #drop column customerID and tenure
            df_2.drop(columns= ['tenure'], axis=1, inplace=True)   

            new_df__dummies = pd.get_dummies(df_2[['gender', 'SeniorCitizen', 'Partner', 'Dependents', 'PhoneService',
           'MultipleLines', 'InternetService', 'OnlineSecurity', 'OnlineBackup',
           'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport', 'StreamingTV', 'StreamingMovies',
           'Contract', 'PaperlessBilling', 'PaymentMethod','tenure_group']])

            single = model.predict(new_df__dummies.tail(1))
            probablity = model.predict_proba(new_df__dummies.tail(1))[:,1]
    
            if single==1:
             o1 = "This customer is likely to be churned!!"
             o2 = "Confidence: {}".format(probablity*100)
            else:
             o1 = "This customer is likely to continue!!"
             o2 = "Confidence: {}".format(probablity*100)
        
            return render_template('prediction.html', output1=o1, output2=o2, 
                           query1  = request.form['query1'], 
                           query2  = request.form['query2'],
                           query3  = request.form['query3'],
                           query4  = request.form['query4'],
                           query5  = request.form['query5'], 
                           query6  = request.form['query6'], 
                           query7  = request.form['query7'], 
                           query8  = request.form['query8'], 
                           query9  = request.form['query9'], 
                           query10 = request.form['query10'], 
                           query11 = request.form['query11'], 
                           query12 = request.form['query12'], 
                           query13 = request.form['query13'], 
                           query14 = request.form['query14'], 
                           query15 = request.form['query15'], 
                           query16 = request.form['query16'], 
                           query17 = request.form['query17'],
                           query18 = request.form['query18'], 
                           query19 = request.form['query19'])
        else:
            return render_template('prediction.html', query="")


app.run()
```